# Check if specific file exists inside zipped static resource?

Tags: visualforce, controller, pdf, static-resources

I have a static resource in my org 'Customer_Logo', inside that I have the logo of all my customer, called like : AccountNumber.jpg

I take the Account number in the controller of a VF page render as PDF and use this in VF page to take logo.
Example:

```
<apex:image  url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Customer_Logo, 'images/'+ customerLogo + '.jpg')}" style="width: 100px;height: 100px"/>
```

where :

```
String customerLogo=[Select id,Account_Number__c from Account where...].Account_Number__c;
```

Sometimes I doesn't have all my customer logo so the resource is not found and inside the pdf a grey static image is shown. Is there a way to check if a static resource exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, you should be able to do this:

```
String customerLogo=[Select Account_Number__c from Account where...].Account_Number__c,
    tempUrl = '/resource/Customer_Logo/images/'+customerLogo+'.jpg',
    imageUrl = '/resource/defaultlogo';
try {
    new PageReference(tempUrl).getContent();
    imageUrl = tempUrl;
} catch(VisualforceException e) {
    // 404 error happened here
}
return imageUrl;
```

This code uses Apex Code to manually verify the image's existence before using the URL.